# Multiple indexes with the same prefix

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Let's suppose I have the following fields:

```
userId: int
userSituation: int
userStatus: int
```

and if I create the following indexes:

```
{ userId, userSituation }
{ userId, userStatus }
```

Will MongoDB benefit in some way? For example, both indexes start from the same ordered index of `userId` ? Or would I be better of changing the 2nd index to  `{ userStatus , userId}`, so I would have a prefix for `userStatus`?

Comment: See [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/) topic _Create Queries that Ensure Selectivity_.

Comment: That depends on what kind of queries you want to run.

Comment: @Thilo currently i'd only need to quer by userId.userSituation or userId.userStatus. But if the cost is the same for creating both indexes, would I be better off creating an index { userStatus, userId } in case I need to query by userStatus in the future?

Comment: @prasad_ interesting, I took M201 but haven't heard about selectivity, thanks

Comment: If you have different queries in the future, you can adjust your indexes accordingly. There is no need to create them "just in case".